# Twig - dynamically replace GET parameter's value

Tags: symfony, parameters, request, twig

Is there a way to replace a GET parameter value from twig?

For example, I have a page at this address:

```
http://localhost/app_dev.php/test/?param1=40&sort=name
```

And in my twig I want to build 3 links like this:

```
http://localhost/app_dev.php/test/?param1=40&sort=name 
http://localhost/app_dev.php/test/?param1=40&sort=address 
http://localhost/app_dev.php/test/?param1=40&sort=code
```

For now I added the "&sort" parameter once again at the end on the URL, but this solution is actually a "patch" and it sucks!

```
<a href="{{app.request.requesturi}}&sort=address">address</a>
```

In this example I only have 2 parameters, but in reality I have around 6 parameters, because the link that's generated it's obtained by submitting a .

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: well... I need to get the current URL and then replace the value of an existent parameter. In the example provided I want to rebuild the URL with a different value for "sort"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),
   app.request.query.all|merge({'sort': 'address'})) }}
```

It gets the current route and all query parameters which are merged with the one you like to update before they are appended.

Comment: you... I like you ^^

Answer (score 2):

Symfony/Twig `path` function accept optional params. If these params are part of the route, they're handled by router but if they're not, they are passed as GET parameters.

So, if your corresponding route is, for example, `my_route` :

```
<a href="{{ path('my_route', {'param1':40, 'sort':'address'}) }}">address</a>
```

Comment: but what if I have a list of 6 parameters? I need to build the link for all the params? The link generated is obtain by submitting a <form>...

Comment: @insertusernamehere has your answer. It keeps request parameters and replace only those you want to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If your route has params (like `/blog/post/{slug}`) and you want automatically retrieve them your `path()` should be like this, extending @insertusernamehere answer:

```
<a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'sort':'address')})) }}">address</a>
```

To keep all query parameters and replace the ones you need, concatenate the `merge`s:

```
<a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge(app.request.query.all)|merge({'sort':'address')})) }}">address</a>
```

This code has been tested with Symfony 5.4/6.2 on Twig 3.